# Using tax_query creates a 0 = 1 in $wp_query->request

Tags: wordpress

This is my first attempt at modifying the main query using the `pre_get_posts` action/filter

This is the function currently hooked to it:

```
function advanced_product_search_filter($query)
{
  if(!is_admin() &&
     is_main_query() && 
     is_search() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product')
  {
    $keyword = $_GET['s'];

    if($_GET['exactly'])
      $keyword = $_GET['s'] . ' "'. $_GET['exactly'] . '"';

    if($_GET['without'])
    {
      $excluded = exclude_product_keyword_search($_GET['without'], 
                    $_GET['pname'],
                    $_GET['pcode']
                  );
      $query->set('post__not_in', $excluded);
    }

    if($_GET['pname'])
      $query->set('s', $keyword);
    else
      $query->set('s', '');

    if($_GET['pcode'])
    {
      $tax_queries = $query->get('tax_query');
      $tax_queries[] = array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'pa_ordering-code',
          'field' => 'name',
          'terms' => array($keyword),
          'operator' => 'LIKE'
        )
      );
      $query->set('tax_query', $tax_queries);
    }
  }
}
```

This is a plugin built on top of a `WooCommerce` installation. So basically this function *tries* to support searching a `WooCommerce` product either through the standard search (title and content) or an attribute search on a custom attribute called `Ordering Code` which is `pa_ordering-code` in the `term_taxonomy` table

Other parts of the code works fine, I can modify the `s` and `post__not_in` vars without any problems, but if I try to use the `tax_query` it, the query seems to break down.

To give you an idea, when I try this:

```
?s=foo&post_type=product&pname=1&pcode=1&without=non&exactly=foo+bar
```

dumping the `WHERE` clause, I see this:

```
AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (219) 
AND 0 = 1 
AND 
(
  (
    (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%foo%') OR 
    (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%foo%')
  ) AND (
    (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%foo bar%') OR 
    (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%foo bar%')
  )
) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND
( 
  (
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility' AND
    CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('visible','search')
  ) 
)
```

Notice the `AND 0 = 1`? When I dump the `JOIN` clause, I become sure that the `tax_query` parameter isn't being interpreted properly since I only see the `postmeta` table in there. No `terms`, `term_relationships`, or `term_taxonomy` table.

And I also tried simply overwriting the existing `tax_query` (if there is one) by doing this:

```
$args = array(
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'pa_ordering-code',
    'field' => 'name',
    'terms' => array($keyword),
    'operator' => 'LIKE'
  )
);
$query->set('tax_query', $args);
```

But I still could not get it to work. Any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Setting **include_children** parameter to **false** solved my problem:

```
$args = array(
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-name',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => array(1, 2, 3, 4),
    'include_children' => false,
    'operator' => 'AND'
  )
);
```

The error seems to occur when there are nested terms in the tax_query (e.g. 2 is a child of 1).

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when such taxonomy, or taxonomy parameter you search by does not exist. For instance taxonomy name has spelling error, or slug name if you are searching by slug. 
In this case it's hard to say since you rewritten the taxonomy query.